# Not accessing pointers to struct as parameter in another function

Tags: c, pointers

I have this example file

#### example.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *name;
} player;

void
playercreation(player *p, int nr)
{
    p=malloc(sizeof(player));
    char stringtemp[10];
    printf("Create player %d:\nWrite your name (max 10 letters): ", nr);
    scanf("%s", stringtemp);
    p->name=malloc(sizeof(*(p->name))*11);
    strcpy(p->name, stringtemp);
    p->drawnlines=0;
    p->squares=0;
}

void
playercreationMenu(player *p1, player *p2)
{
    playercreation(p1, 1);
    playercreation(p2, 1);
}

void
confirmPlayer(player *p)
{
    printf("player %s created\n", p->name);
}

int
main(void)
{
    player p1, p2;
    playercreationMenu(&p1, &p2);
    confirmPlayer(&p1);
    confirmPlayer(&p2);
}
```

In my real program this gives me a segmentation fault as im trying to access something in the player structure that does not exist as the player never is created, but in this example its shown by the fact that the players name is (null) although the name was given in the playercreationMenu function. Why is this?

Comment: You should compile with all warnings and debugging info, and learn to use a debugger and a memory leak detector. On Linux, that means compile with `gcc -Wall -g`, debug with `gdb` and `valgrind`

Comment: In the function `playercreation`, I see the variable `count` being used without being initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write

```
player p1, p2;
playercreationMenu(&p1, &p2);
```

But in the constructor function, you have

```
void playercreation(player *p, int nr)
{
    p = malloc(sizeof(player));

    ...
}
```

So you're assigning a `malloc()`ated block of memory to the local variable containing the address of an already-allocated (on the stack!) structure... Drop the call to `malloc()` and you'll be fine.

You're also using the `count` variable before initializing it or assigning a value to it:

```
int count;
...
p->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (count + 1));
```

So one, this is undefined behavior, two, you'll get a quite random amount of memory (which makes it possible to write past its bounds -> another undefined behavior), or a NULL pointer if this would result in too much memory allocated (a third undefined behavior).

Three UBs in one line - **do expect it to crash.**

Comment: @Aniket Yep. And use whitespaces, don't spell out `sizeof(char)` cause it's always one, etc, etc...

Comment: I'd have used `p->name = malloc(sizeof(*(p->name)) ...) `. if might become a `wchar_t *` one day. @Aniket

Comment: @alk yes, that's the ideal solution I didn't even dare to mention ;)

Comment: @alk, and I always wondered why my company's code-review team discouraged `sizeof(type)` with `malloc()`.

Comment: @Aniket [Linus Torvalds](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) also advises this. Also keep in mind that `TYPE *p = malloc(sizeof(TYPE));` is redundand as well - the type should be implied :)

Comment: @Aniket Oups, and you're already working at a company? There's a bunch of things you should learn yet.

Comment: yeah, a lot of this is forgiven at embedded end :-)

Comment: Thanks for insightful comments. Can I make a follow-up? I wonder why I dont need to assign memory to the struct in main, and why it is made automatically, and why this is not the case for the name variable in the player struct? Please remember Im learning this stuff now, so its simply not possible for me to know all these things that you know.. Thanks.

Comment: @patriques `player p1;` declares a variable of type `player`, which is a struct. It is **not a pointer.** When you declare it, memory on the stack gets allocated for it. (It's deallocated after the end of its scope.) In `struct player`, the name variable is a pointer, that's just an integer number that points to somewhere in memory. You need to reserve some bytes of memory and assign the address of that block to the pointer to make it functional.

Answer (score 3):

`count` is not initialized. Garbage in garbage out.

Comment: And a good compiler, with all warnings enabled, would have warned you. `gcc -Wall` does warn about that.

Comment: +1 ... also for "*garbage in garbage out*" which I somehow hadn't heard for a long time ... :-)

Comment: @H2CO3 Could you be so kind and rephrase/explain "*aperceive*" as me and my dictionary do not know this word.

Comment: @alk Whoops. I meant "perceive".

Answer (score 2):

Your code has problems in these two lines:

```
p=malloc(sizeof(player));
int count;
```

The malloc is not necessary as you are already allocating space for the player structures on the stack when you declare them in main().

You are not initializing count which means it has garbage value. When you call malloc with count, you could be requesting for a arbitrarily large amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

For one, you never initialize `count`, as a few other people have pointed out. This means that it is an arbitrary value, and so you have no idea what you are passing into `malloc`.

You also probably shouldn't use `scanf`, as you will overflow your buffer if someone types more than 10 characters. I would recommend `fgets` instead.

In addition, you are first declaring your players on the stack, and passing pointers to them into `playercreationMenu`. That is fine. Then you pass those into `playercreation`, which is also fine. In `playercreation`, you then overwrite the *pointer* to the player with a pointer returned from `malloc`. So you never actually do anything to the original `player`s that you allocated on the stack in `main`.

As Basile suggests, it would be a good idea to compile with `-Wall` to get more compiler warnings, and pay close attention to them. Actually, I prefer `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`; `-Wall` doesn't actually give you all warnings, so `-Wextra` turns some more useful ones on, and `-Werror` turns warnings into errors, so that you cannot ignore them.

Comment: +1 perfect sum-up of all the answers + comments, neatly packaged. :-)

Comment: @Aniket Yeah, I was slow writing this up, so it wound up being a repeat of what everyone else wrote, but I figured it was worth to have a single summary answer anyhow.